# Clean path with the same name as a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory /news within the root directory and I have a /news clean path too.
I have some subdirectories and files in the /news directory.

I need to support the clean path /news (with same extra $_GET parameters sometimes) and allow to linking to real files and subdirectories within the real /news directory.

My current .htaccess looks like:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /news/?$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but there are some issues with ajax requests (there is no problem on casual user requests) to the /news path if there are some GET parameters and it always adds slash at the end of the path, for example I enter example.com/news, so it redirects to example.com/news/.

How to use the same clean path as existing directory in this case?

Comment: Try commenting out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /news/?$ [OR]` line

Comment: @anubhava In this case I get the content from the /news directory on the example.com/news request. I want to get the content from the /news clean path instead.

Comment: From where `/news` will get content from if not from `/news/index.php`?

Comment: @anubhava the htaccess is from the root directory, not from the /news.

Comment: That I already know, my question wasn't that. Let me try asking again. When URL in browser is `/news/` where will content come from internally? Is it `/news.php` OR `/index.php` OR `/news/index.php`?

Comment: @anubhava should be from /index.php.

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Following rule should work for you in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Make sure there is no `/news/.htaccess` to override this.**

Comment: No difference in a result. However I see the first ajax request to the "http:// domain.com/news" is redirected (301) to "http:// www.domain.com/news", but I have disabled the www. prefix in  htaccess (I use standard Drupal file http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.htaccess?id=7.31 with uncommented the 2 lines about www. prefix forwarding to non www.)

Comment: Well then test this in a new browser to avoid old caches for `www` addition.